# Replace elements of a list based on a prefix

Tags: list-manipulation

I have this list;

> a={{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1,
>      1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}

and I would like to do a replace based on the prefix of each element of the list. For example, if the prefix is {0} I would like to modify to this

> a={1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0}

or if the prefix is {1,0} the list would become;

> a={0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0}

I'd need it to be general so that if the elements and prefix size changes it will still work. Also, I worked on this all day and got nowhere due to my procedural programming background. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
a={{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}};
Cases[a, {b_, _, _} -> If[b == 0, 1, 0]]
Cases[a, {b_, c_, _} -> If[{b,c} =={1,0}, 1, 0]]
```

For changeable length, use ___ in place of _, like `{a_,b_,___}`
This would do just fine. Simply replace the rules to make it match other patterns

Comment: Thanks, it works. So what if the elements of "a" are variable length, e.g., {0,0,0,0,0}, would I have to modify the Case patterns {b_,._,._}  to {b_,._,._,._,._} ?

Comment: @user58558 You could use `BlankSequence` (I.e. `__`) e.g. `{b_, __}` to match sequences of arbitrary length.

Comment: @MarcoB BlankSequence worked. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** `f4` and `f5` should work as is in version 8. Variants of `f1`, `f2` and `f3` that avoid the functions and forms that are only available in later versions are:

```
ClearAll[f1b, f2b, f3b]
f1b[l_List, {p__}] := Boole[MatchQ[#, {p, ___}] & /@ l]
f2b[l_List, p_List] := Boole[MatchQ[#[[;; Min[Length@#, Length@p]]], p] & /@ l]
f3b[l_List, p_List] := Boole[Equal[#[[;; Min[Length@#, Length@p]]], p] & /@ l]

b = {{0}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, 
  {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}};
f1b[b, {0}]
```

> {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}

```
f1b[b, {1, 0}]
```

> {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}

```
Equal @@ (#[b, {0}] & /@ {f1b, f2b, f3b})
```

> True

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3, f4, f5]
f1[l_List, {p__}] := Boole[MatchQ[{p, ___}] /@ l]
f2[l_List, p_List] := Boole[MatchQ[p] /@ l[[All, ;; UpTo@Length@p]]]
f3[l_List, p_List] := Boole[EqualTo[p] /@ l[[All, ;; UpTo @ Length@p]]]
f4[a_, {p__}] := Block[{f}, f[{p, ___}] = 1; f[_] := 0; f /@ a];
f5[a_, {p__}] := Replace[a, {{p, ___} :> 1, {__} :> 0}, 1]

f1[a, {0}]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}

```
f1[a, {1, 0}]
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}

```
 f5[a, {0}] == f4[a, {0}] == f3[a, {0}] == f2[a, {0}] == f1[a, {0}]
```

> True

```
f3[a, {1, 0}] == f2[a, {1, 0}] == f1[a, {1, 0}]
```

> True

```
b= {{0}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, 
   {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1,1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}} ;

f1[b, {0}]
```

> {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}

```
f1[b, {0}] == f2[b, {0}] == f3[b, {0}] == f4[b, {0}] == f5[b, {0}]
```

> True

```
f1[b, {1,0}]
```

> {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}

```
f1[b, {1, 0}] == f2[b, {1, 0}] == f4[b, {1, 0}] == f5[b, {1, 0}]
```

> True

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to have to study this one.  Will this still work with variable elements in "a", e.g. instead of {0,0,0} they might be {0,0,0,0,0}....etc.

Comment: @user58558, all three should work for lists with variable lengths.

Comment: Doesn't run on my computer, I have version 8 if that matters.  f1 & f2 generate error that MatchQ requires two inputs.  Also, EqualTo and UpTo not default commands or not defined.

Comment: @user58558, the operator form `MathQ[form]` of `MathcQ` is new in versions 10+. It is equivalent to `MatchQ[#, form]&`. `EqualTo` is also new in version 10.3. I will update with versions that should work in version 8.

Comment: rev b functions work in version 8, thanks.  In first code block f1[b, {0}] should be f1b[b,{0}] and perhaps elsewhere in your update.